# Получение строки из потока, получающего WebResponse

Tags: c#

Есть код, обращающийся к некому веб-серверу с помощью `GET`, который возвращает строку. Единственный мне известный способ - создать поток, но как из этого потока получить строку, которую вернул сервер?

```
WebRequest _request = WebRequest.Create(URL);
WebResponse _response = _request.GetResponse();
Stream stream = _response.GetResponseStream();
```

Comment: вот это стул, на нем сидят. вот это стрим, его readят

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, тут-укажите-кодировку))
{
    var s = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: тут-укажите-кодировку это Encoding.UTF8